# Start nodejs app on linux server with ssh-if i close the ssh connection,app stopped why?)

Tags: node.js, linux, debian

Start nodejs app on linux server with ssh(if i close the ssh connection,app stopped why?)
1-create nodejs app -its oke
2-run on linux server -its oke(i stop the apache server)
But if i close the ssh connection(with my windows pc),app stopped.How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most correct thing to do is to write a service file for it so whatever init system you have (likely systemd) will keep it running and manage the start/stop/restart stuff for you.

Failing that (and I don't blame you...) you can run it within the `screen` utility.  Launch it with `screen -d -m /path/to/start/script` and then you can come back later and reconnect to it with `screen -r` or `screen -r <pid of the screen session>`.

Note that launching it that way won't restart it, etc.  To do that, you could do something like

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
 sleep 3s
 /path/to/start/script
done
```

And call that with the screen command.

Comment: i found a module -forever :D but ty for your attention please look https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: @seferftsukran thanks but i avoid node/angular/et al like the plague - not my kind of coding. But I'll take you from bare metal to a wonderful complete back end w/ REST api so *you* can use node/angular/et al :)

Comment: i try with nohup node server.js & again same error;but i believe we can do this later.(because nodejs is new)

Comment: @seferftsukran - `screen` will do it. I've done it with `screen`.  i may not like node/etc but that doesn't mean i've not done any work in it...

Comment: ty @ivanivan i install the screen and works perfectly:D( ı can use with nodemon)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [nohup](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) command to start the application. Like:

```
nohup THE_COMMAND_YOU_DONT_WANT_TO_STOP_WHEN_YOU_LOGOUT &
```

With nodemon it might be helpful to put the command to start the server in a file called myserver.sh containing:

```
nodemon server.js
```

Make sure the file is executable:

```
chmod +x myserver.js
```

And then run

```
nohup myserver.sh &
```

Comment: please write an example

Comment: There is an issue with using nodemon in this way (see https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/296 ). A workaround that should work is to put your command into a script and running nohup on that script.

Will edit my answer because of formatting

Comment: not solve my problem:D this is general problem but ty:D